# How to plot a 3D decision boundary in Python?

Tags: python, plot, 3d, svm

I am trying to plot a 3D SVM with a rbf kernel but can't seem to get it to work. I have seem posts about 2d plots and I understand these.

What I am doing is

```
xx = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min,x_max,1)
# similar for yy and zz
Z= clf.decision_function(np.c_[xx.ravel(),yy.ravel(),zz.ravel()])
```

How do I proceed after this step?